# Simple multiplexing node.js stream - chunk concatenated issue

Tags: node.js, stream, chunks, multiplexing

Im trying to implement a simple node.js stream multiplexer/demultiplexer.

Currently while implementing the multiplexing mechanism i noticed that the output of the multiplexer gets concatenated into a single chunk.

```js
const { PassThrough, Transform } = require("stream");

class Mux extends PassThrough {

    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
    }

    input(id, options) {

        let encode = new Transform({
            transform(chunk, encoding, cb) {

                let buf = Buffer.alloc(chunk.length + 1);
                buf.writeUInt8(id, 0);

                chunk.copy(buf, 1);

                cb(null, buf);

            },
            ...options
        });

        encode.pipe(this);

        return encode;

    };

};

const mux = new Mux();

mux.on("readable", () => {
    console.log("mux >", mux.read())
});

const in1 = mux.input(1);
const in2 = mux.input(2);


in1.write(Buffer.alloc(3).fill(255));
in2.write(Buffer.alloc(3).fill(127));
```

Output looks like this: `mux > <Buffer 01 ff ff ff 02 7f 7f 7f>`.
I would have thought that i receive two `console.log` outputs.

Expected output:

`mux > <Buffer 01 ff ff ff>`

`mux > <Buffer 02 7f 7f 7f>`

Can some one explains why i only get one "readable" event and a concatenated chunk from both inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`data`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) event and read from the callback:

> The 'data' event is emitted whenever the stream is relinquishing ownership of a chunk of data to a consumer.

```js
mux.on("data", d => {
    console.log("mux >", d)
});
```

This now yields:

```
mux > <Buffer 01 ff ff ff>
mux > <Buffer 02 7f 7f 7f>
```

---

Why `readable` is only emitted once is explained [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable) as well:

> The 'readable' event will also be emitted once the end of the stream data has been reached but before the 'end' event is emitted.

`data` and `readable` behave differently. In your case `readable` is never emitted until the end of the stream data has been reached, which returns all the data at once. `data` is emitted on each available chunk.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, is this not the "old" way? Are there downsides to use the "data" event instead of "readable"?

Comment: @Marc I don't think it's an "old way". `data` and `readable` behave differently. In your case `readable` is never emitted until the end of the stream data has been reached (see my edit), which returns all the data at once. `data` is emitted on each available chunk.

Comment: I have just now discoverd that this happens with transform streams also, any idea why? Should is edit my question or ask a new?

Comment: @Marc I think this would be suitable for a separate question which includes your new code. Would be easier to answer